# Using Validator.TryValidateObject in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Validator.TryValidateObject everytime return true. Why? I tried different field values.
Its my model:

```
public class CompanyPreviewMeta
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Изображение")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Текст")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 20, ErrorMessage = "Значение {0} должно содержать от {2} до 100 символов.")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

It's my validation, and "valid" is true everytime:

```
        ValidationContext ValidatorContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
        List<ValidationResult> result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, ValidatorContext, result, true);
```

Comment: where do you have Validator.TryValidateobject function? are you doing this on form post?

Comment: Yes, I do.
Lower code is located in private method, which i call in my method, which object comes out to post.

Comment: I threw your code into linqpad and it worked fine. Did you inspect the model that got passed to the validation function to make sure it has values that would return false upon validation?